# Close MainScreen view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I've noticed that when I switch from my main controller view (mainScreen)
to another view (example: secondScreen), I don't close my mainScreen
and open the secondScreen, I just open my secondScreen
on top of my mainScreen. Is there a way for me to close my mainScreen??
The code I use to switch from mainScreen to secondScreen:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainScreen", bundle: nil) 
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondScreen" 
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
self.loadView() show(secondVC, sender: self)
```

The code I use to return to mainScreen:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

// I use self.dismiss() and self.loadView() as a solution to reload MainScreen.
// I take data from SecondScreen that changes data on MainScreen,
// and I can't succeed it with another way.

If we can't have our MainScreen reloaded, at least making a function that could
change my data every time it load my MainScreen view it would be great!
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Swift 5 - iOS 14

The following code changes your app root totally.

```
func coordinateToSecondVC()
{
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainScreen", bundle: nil) 
    let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondScreen")
    window.rootViewController = secondVC
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

If you want to push your `secondVC` in navigation stack, you can use this:

```
func coordinateToSecondVC()
{
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainScreen", bundle: nil) 
    let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondScreen")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    window.rootViewController = navController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Then easily call the function whenever you want to coordinate to `secondVC`:

```
coordinateToSecondVC()
```